# How To Get Bitbucket Code Insights Report To Show Failures?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a weird problem with Bitbucket pipelines. It seems as though the Tests tab is showing that my unit tests are failing and it shows me exactly which ones failed. However the code insight report itself shows that there are no problems with the unit tests that are being run and that none failed. Here are screenshots and my code. Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Test Tab Showing 1 Test Failed

[image: Test Tab Showing 1 Test Failed]

Code Insight Report Showing Nothing Failed

[image: Code Insight Report Showing Nothing Failed]

Build Info
[image: Build Info]

This is my bitbucket-pipelines.yaml

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    'feature/*':
      - step:
          name: Run Integration Tests
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm cache clean --force
            - node ./scripts/run-tests.js
          after-script:
            - pipe: atlassian/checkstyle-report:0.4.0
              variables:
                REPORT_FAIL_SEVERITY: 'warn'
                CHECKSTYLE_REPORT_TITLE: 'Integration Test Report'
          artifacts:
            - 'tests/**'
```

And this is one of the sample tests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="Mocha Tests" time="10.043" tests="6" failures="0">
  <testsuite name="Root Suite" timestamp="2023-07-04T19:15:23" tests="0" time="0.000" failures="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Delete Token" timestamp="2023-07-04T19:15:23" tests="1" file="/services/token/tests/delete.spec.js" time="6.496" failures="0">
    <testcase name="Delete Token should delete a token" time="0.064" classname="should delete a token">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Create Token" timestamp="2023-07-04T19:15:29" tests="4" file="/services/token/tests/post.spec.js" time="1.952" failures="0">
    <testcase name="Create Token should create a production token with auto generated name" time="0.037" classname="should create a production token with auto generated name">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Create Token should create a production token with user defined name" time="0.022" classname="should create a production token with user defined name">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Create Token should create a sandbox token with auto generated name" time="0.022" classname="should create a sandbox token with auto generated name">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="Create Token should create a sandbox token with user defined name" time="0.024" classname="should create a sandbox token with user defined name">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="Update Token" timestamp="2023-07-04T19:15:31" tests="1" file="/services/token/tests/put.spec.js" time="1.594" failures="0">
    <testcase name="Update Token should update a token" time="0.027" classname="should update a token">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

So why would the Tests tab generate the tests that failed but the Code Insight report show 0 Violations along with 0 for everything else.

Comment: Your pipe is trying to read checkstyle reports, not automated test results. You need a different pipe, or make one yourself, to do that